# Loop in JSON to add markers to Google Map

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, laravel-blade

I try to display a map with multiple markers. These markers I try to loop, but I can not use a foreach loop in the JSON input. Does anybody know how I add a loop to add more to the markers-array?

It is in Laravel and I use a package https://gitlab.com/gonoware/laravel-maps

A single map is working but the map with multiple markers not..

This is the code.

```
<div>
                @map([
                'lat' => $map->lat,
                'lng' => $map->long,
                'zoom' => 15,
                'markers' => [
                [
                'title' => $map->address,
                'lat' => $map->lat,
                'lng' => $map->long,
                ],
                ],
                ])
            </div>
```

It is working as a single map with one marker but I don;t know how to loop it.

This is the code from the package

```
<div class="gnw-map-service gnw-map-service__{{ $service }}">
    <div class="gnw-map fade" data-map-{{ $service }}="{{ json_encode(compact('lat', 'lng', 'zoom')) }}" data-map-service="{{ json_encode(config('vendor.maps.services.'.$service)) }}" data-map-markers="{{ json_encode($markers ?? []) }}"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks! Sam

Comment: you can try with javascript.

Comment: I did but I can not do a JS loop in the middle of the JSON section.